# Angular 4 can't find name (generics)

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I have a problem with Angular 4. TypeScript doesn't compile and gives me errors when I run `ng serve`.

> Error in my-data.service.ts (9,30) Cannot find name 'Category'
>   Error in my-data.service.ts (13,17) Cannot find name 'Category'

**my-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class MyDataService {
    database:string = 'http://localhost/exploremo2/material/database/';
    database2:string = 'http://192.168.254.105/exploremo2/material/database/';
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    getCategories(): Observable<Category[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.database+'getdata/getallcategory.php')
            .map(res => {
                return res.json().results.map(item => {
                    return new Category(item);
                });
            });
    }
}
```

**add.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit   } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { fadeInAnimation } from '../_animations/fadein';
import { slideInOutAnimation } from '../_animations/slide';
import { MyDataService} from '../my-data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css','../app.component.css'],
  providers: [Title],
  animations: [slideInOutAnimation],
})
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
    private Categories:Observable<any>;
    constructor( private title: Title, private MyDataService:MyDataService) { 
     this.title.setTitle('Add');
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.Categories = this.MyDataService.getCategories();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never import Category in your script file.

Comment: Import Category type in your component.

Comment: @Igor what would the Category be? i only followed this tutorial i just renamed <SearchItem[]> in the tutorial : [Http with Observables](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never import Category in your script file yet you use it as a return type inside your `Observable`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// ADD IMPORT STATEMENT
import { Category } from './some-file`

@Injectable()
export class MyDataService { /* no change from OP */ }
```

Alternatively you can do one of the following

1. Define an exportable Category type or interface in your service code file
2. Change occurrences of `Category` to `any`, this might be ok if you do not do anything with those instances in your code itself but only use the instances in your templates as templates do not benefit from type safty.

*exported category in the Service file*

```
export interface Category {
// members here
}
```

Comment: what would the Category be? i only followed this tutorial i just renamed <SearchItem[]> in the tutorial : [Http with Observables](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/)

Comment: @KarlJoshuaDuroyBernal - I do not know what Category is, its your type that you want to do something with. You have some other options I added to my answer.

Comment: did you see the link to the tutorial, how come the tutorial didnt need an interface. i've been having this problem for 2 weeks now :(

Comment: @KarlJoshuaDuroyBernal - [Using a domain model](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-promises/#_using_a_domain_model)

Comment: thank you, you just saved my 2 weeks. how careless of me to not check the previous page/topic for that tutorial. you sir are commended.

Comment: @KarlJoshuaDuroyBernal - glad to help.